# Add images to UIScrollView horizontally with paging

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to display images in a horizontal row using pages,with each page containing 4 images probably separated by a little space of one line or without space. As the user scrolls horizontally, next four images are displayed in the center of view. But using this code:

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight/4, screenWidth, screenHeight/4)];
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
    int k=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
        [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", k];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            CGRect imageFrame=CGRectMake(0, k*screenHeight/4, screenWidth/5, screenHeight/5);
            imageView.frame=imageFrame;
            [awesomeView addSubview:imageView];
            k++;
        }
```

images are displayed vertically on first page view. Moreover it looks like vertical scrolling is working. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
CGRect imageFrame=CGRectMake(0, k*screenHeight/4, screenWidth/5, screenHeight/5);
```

You are messing with frame your imageView (inside UIView - awesomeView).

Your `k` variable is 1,2,3,4

So i assume that you have 4 imageViews in vertical, and next 'column' with four image on the left, right?

Also you don't set `contentSize` for your `scrollView` anywhere so, you might not see the second 'column'